# CDF (mixed) of the positive part of a normal random variable as a mixed distribuition

Tags: probability

$X$ is distribuited as $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, that is $f_X(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt { 2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t-\mu)^2} $. Consider the positive part $X^+ = \max\{X,0\}$. I will calculate the CDF
$$F_{X^+} (t) = \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{for } t <0\\    
  P[X \leq t ] = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt { 2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^2}dy   & \text{for } t \geq 0
\end{cases} $$
How can I show that this is as a linear combination of the distribuition function of a discrete random variable and a distribuition function of a continium random variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $t \geq 0$, consider two cases: $t = 0$ and $t > 0$. If $t = 0$, then,

$$ F_{X^+}(0) = P(X \leq 0) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^0\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}Erfc\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

where $Erfc(x)$ represents the [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function). If $t > 0$, then,

$$ F_{X^+}(t) = P(X < 0) + P(0 \leq X \leq t) = \frac{1}{2}Erfc\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}\right) +\int\limits_{0}^t\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2}dx $$

So really, we have a mixed distribution (discrete and continuous) with CDF,

$$ F_{X^+}(t) = \begin{cases}0 & t < 0\\
\frac{1}{2}Erfc\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}\right) & t = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}Erfc\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}\right) +\int\limits_{0}^t\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2}dx & t > 0 \end{cases}$$

Notice how there's a jump at $t = 0$. This corresponds to the discrete part of the distribution. Thus, we can write $F_{X^+}(t)$ as a sum, $F_{X^+}(t) = F_{X^+}^C(t) + F_{X^+}^D(t)$ where $F_{X^+}^C(t)$ and $F_{X^+}^D(t)$ represent the continuous part and discrete part respectively. Specifically,

$$ F_{X^+}^C(t) =  \begin{cases}
\int\limits_{0}^t\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2}dx & t > 0\\
0 & t \leq 0
\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; F_{X^+}^D(t) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}Erfc\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}\right) & t \geq 0\\
0 & t < 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: I never imagine the erfc function. Now, Has $X^{+}$ a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I'm not advanced in measure theory, but a mixed distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to the sum of the counting and Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Is each component a CDF? If YES, for example, Is $\lim_{t \to \infty}F_{X^{+}}^{C}(t)=1$ true?